# ArcGis Javascript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, mgrs, mouse-cursor

I am trying to make map, that on mouse over displays the mgrs coordinates.

Example map with lat, long: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=map_xycoords

I know about project http://proj4js.org/ but don't know how to implement it.

Is there any ready resource that I could examine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i wrote a blog on this exact topic awhile back.

Using Proj4JS in the ArcGIS API for JavaScript to reproject coordinates on the fly
https://geonet.esri.com/groups/geodev/blog/2014/11/03/use-proj4js-alongside-the-arcgis-api-for-javascript-to-reproject-coordinates-on-the-fly